# Non conformable array error when using rpart with rpy2

Tags: arrays, numpy, python-3.5, decision-tree, rpy2

I'm using `rpart` with `rpy2` (version 2.8.6) on python 3.5, and want to train a decision tree for classification. My code snippet looks like this:

```
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects import DataFrame, Formula
rpart = importr('rpart')
numpy2ri.activate()
pandas2ri.activate()

dataf = DataFrame({'responsev': owner_train_label,
               'predictorv': owner_train_data})
formula = Formula('responsev ~.')
clf = rpart.rpart(formula = formula, data = dataf, method = "class", control=rpart.rpart_control(minsplit = 10, xval = 10))
```

> where owner_train_label is a numpy float64 array of shape (12610,) and
>   owner_train_data is a numpy float64 array of shape (12610,88)

This is the error I'm getting when I run the **last line of code** to fit the data.

```
RRuntimeError: Error in ((xmiss %*% rep(1, ncol(xmiss))) < ncol(xmiss)) & !ymiss : 
non-conformable arrays
```

I get that it is telling me they are non-conformable arrays but I don't know why as for the same training data, I can train using sklearn's Decision tree successfully. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by creating the dataframe using pandas and passing the panadas dataframe to rpart using rpy2's pandas2ri to convert it to R's dataframe.

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects import Formula
rpart = importr('rpart')
pandas2ri.activate()

df = pd.DataFrame(data = owner_train_data)
df['l'] = owner_train_label
formula = Formula('l ~.')
clf = rpart.rpart(formula = formula, data = df, method = "class", control=rpart.rpart_control(minsplit = 10, xval = 10))
```